# As soon as I resize a storyboard view in a view controller my other views disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, storyboard

Effect can be seen here. Xcode 6.1

http://gyazo.com/5848c85087d736de48d49ad59c699221

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known bug. Use Size inspector as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this error by adding some autolayout rules to the objects inside the view.